# after Jquery onDrop, how to Ajax GET and append ActionResult of PartialView to Div

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, drag-and-drop

In a page, I have

`<ul id="myPicsMakeAlbum" > 
    <li id="pic1" data-index-number="picture1"></li>
    <li id="pic2" data-index-number="picture2"></li>
    <li id="pics3" data-index-number="picture3"></li>
</ul>`

list of thumbnails/imgs and  *where user can drag and drop those thumbnails of documents*.

Following the `OnDrop()` event: How do I trigger/male an Ajax call to the ASP MVC Action Method, with the `id` of the list item.

Then append the return ActionResult from the partialview/View as a nest div inside the container.

```
<div id="container"></div> 

    $("#containere").droppable({ 
        accept: "#container",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            //how to make the ajax call with item id?
        } 
});
```

**How do I wrap this inside an onDrop Call with a *unique* Id of the item**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Home/GetMyPartialView/",
    data: ThumNailId,                //** how do I wire this up to the dragDrop**
    success: function (myresult) {     
        if (myresult.Status === 300) { //300 is an arbitrary value I just made up right now
            showPopup("You do not have access to that.");
        }

        $("#Container").html(myresult.ViewString); //the HTML I returned from the controller
    },
    error: function (errorData) { onError(errorData); }
});
```

Should I use Html.Partial or Partial View here?

Comment: How are you giving your `<li>` elements an 'id'?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have edited the list to show the id's. Also, is it better to use the _HTML5 **data-val** attributes over the **Id**_, please advise which is better to send as unique Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ui` parameter contains the information about the element that was dragged, so you can use

```
$("#containere").droppable({ 
    accept: "#container",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var id = ui.draggable.data('index-number'); // returns 'picture1' if the 1st li element is dragged/dropped
        // or var id = ui.draggable.attr('id'); if you want the 'pic1' value
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetMyPartialView", "Home")', // don't hard code url's
            data: { ThumNailId: id },
            ....
        });     
    } 
});
```

Note, this assumes your method is signature is

```
public ActionResult GetMyPartialView(string ThumNailId)
```

Comment: Thanks, I can mark as answer (yes getpartalview sig is correct), one question will this work with the return  or get stuck in the http response stream `$("#Container").html(myresult.ViewString); //the HTML I returned from the controller` . You also used the data value data-`index-number` over list id, is this better. thanks

Comment: Using a `data-` attribute is better (the `id` attribute is for identifying an element in the DOM used by css and javascript selectors). If your method returns a partial view, it will work fine - but you don't seem to be doing that (you appear to be returning an object containing properties `Status` and `ViewString` and its unclear why - why not return a partial view or `null` and then you can just use `success: function (response) { if (response) { $("#Container").html(response); } else { showPopup(...); } }`)

Comment: Thanks for the expl :) going to try with `ActionResult`  and your suggestion, `success: function (response) { if (response) { $("#Container").html(response); }` - 1) will this also work for any html, like a if I return a chart. I am finding that its dumping all the appends inside the same div,  2) how can I append each returning pic inside _a new <div>_  `document.createElement('div')` right now everything for BS3 is inside the same div, I want to give them separate divs. 3) is it possible to make them sortable or should i put sortable on the main `container div`

Comment: @transformer, Without a bit more information, its hard to know what your wanting to do, and how you want the html your generating to look like. I don't even know what the html your returning from the method is. I suggest you ask a new question with a bit more detail.